# Non-transitive package dependencies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have a package X depending on another package Y. By default (Visual Studio 2015 Upd3 + nuget 3.5) any project referencing to package X will be updated with reference to package Y too. The issue is, customers of X do not need reference to Y at all, as API of package Y is not and should not be exposed to customers.

So, the expected behavior is following: after adding reference to package X, content of package Y should be copied into output folder on build, but package Y should not be added into project references.

Is there any way to so?

Theoretically we can include sources of the infrastructure package Y into our project X (both projects are opensource under MIT license) but I'd prefer to use more or less standard approach.

Example of cases why we need it:

- The case we're investigating right now: nuget package with test helper that ensures that PDB files matches to the sources (references `Microsoft.DiaSymReader` package). We do not want all our test projects to reference `Microsoft.DiaSymReader` assembly.
- More or less theoretical one (not an issue for now but will be a problem if the project will be pushed into production): custom script engine that uses Roslyn to compile and run the scripts. We do not want references to the Roslyn assemblies in all projects that will use our script engine.

Latter case is much worse as we cannot merge roslyn sources into our project, obviously, and cannot distribute roslyn binaries as a part of our package, too.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the dlls of Package Y as content files in Package X, which will not add Y dlls into the project that installed Package X.

Following steps shows how to create Package X with Y dlls as content files.

1. Add Y dlls into Package X project by Add -> Existing Items.
2. Select all Y dlls and right-click to open the Properties window, set the "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy always".
3. Pack Project X as Package X with nuget.exe

Now when you open the Package X.nupkg file with [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/releases/view/629447), you will find the Y dlls stored in content folder. And when you install Package X on other project, the Y dlls will be added into the project as a content file. After build the project, the Y dlls will be copied to output directory.

Comment: It's the same thing @botond.botos suggested. Will result in versioning issues if our customers add direct reference to the Y package.

Comment: If your customers add direct reference to the Y dlls which has different versions with your X package, they could Redirecting Assembly Versions in app's configuration file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Yep, but nuget consolidate feature will not work for such conflicts, they had to be resolved manually. Not an option if the package Y is huge, roslyn as example.

Comment: Yes, current version NuGet will not work for such conflicts. And it is the same in common project, we need to resolve the confilicts issue in project manually.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the author of package X, it is up to you what you include in your `nupkg` file. You could also include third party dlls as well.

Although it is technically possible, I don't recommend doing so. Think of the consumers of your package X, who one day might decide to use package Y. Suddenly they will get runtime errors because X is expecting different version of Y.

Comment: Yes, we're considering this option too but it can result in unresolvable dependency conflict. As example: we supply Y.dll v1.0 as a part of our package X, third-party project references our package X and then adds explicit reference to package Y v2.0. It's definitely no-go for large infrastructure dependencies such as Roslyn. So we'd prefer to stay with normal nuget dependencies but without including them into customer' project references